# The connection among Terminal Total Difficulty (TTD), Difficulty, and Total Difficulty

Tags: eth-2.0, difficulty, difficulty-bomb, the-merge

What is the connection between Terminal Total Difficulty (TTD), Difficulty, and Total Difficulty?

Why can Total Difficulty increase if Difficulty decreases?

---

I know that:

difficulty: QUANTITY - integer of the difficulty for this block.

totalDifficulty: QUANTITY - integer of the total difficulty of the chain until this block.

And I understand what Terminal Total Difficulty (TTD) is in this [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/129860/what-is-terminal-total-difficulty-ttd?newreg=68ed101365b7488993fba699312a8684)

I know that the Hash Rate is proportional to difficulty of the blocks, so if Hash Rate increase then difficulty of the blocks also increase. And because the definition of totalDifficulty is

> integer of the total difficulty of the chain until this block.

So it makes me understand that the more difficulty, the more total difficulty. And therefore, when total difficulty increases, it will reach the TTD, and that time The Merge will be successful.

But when I do statistic on Ropsten testnet. I saw the difficulty was decreasing, while the totalDifficulty was increasing[image]

Can anybody help me to understand why the Difficulty (and hash rate) is decreasing, while Total Difficulty is increasing to reach the TTD? I think the Difficulty (and hash rate) need to be increasing for the increase of Total Difficulty because of its definition: Total Difficulty is integer of the total difficulty of the chain until this block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each block has a `difficulty`.

`totalDifficulty` is the sum of all the `difficulty` of the block and all previous blocks.  Another way to describe `totalDifficulty` is "cumulative difficulty", but cumulative is a longer and not necessarily simpler word.

Even if hashrate decreases, `difficulty` is still larger than 0.  So `totalDifficulty` will keep increasing and eventually exceed `TTD`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. As you said totalDifficulty is the sum of all the difficulty of the block and all previous blocks. So it means if totalDifficulty want  to increase, so the difficulty need to be increased. However, in the Ropsten testnet example, the totalDifficulty is increasing, while the difficulty is decreasing. I don't get it when "totalDifficulty is the sum of all the difficulty of the block and all previous block". That is my concern

Comment: Difficulty does not need to increase: if difficulty drops to 1, totalDifficulty will still increase by 1 each time...

Comment: ohh, so do you know what are the factors can impact the totalDifficulty ? and do you know how to calculate the totalDifficulty ( the calculation ignore the difficulty factor)?

Comment: Let's just have three blocks in order, with difficulty 10, 11, 12. The totalDifficulty at each block is 10, 21, 33. Do you see that? If the next block has difficulty 1, then totalDifficulty will be 34.

Comment: ohhh, I am very appreciate your explanation. It helps me a lots

Comment: Great! I'll leave these comments here in case it helps others.